# Proper Regex to get a value into a URL

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the "configure" value from the following https://example.com/estimate/unit/configure/76yc1d2b-31aa-4b5a-95af-8b0f93b01b00?sid=e9a9a541-9417-43c4-a4e9-746ttdd84e9o

With this regex  (?<=unit/)(.*)(?=\?)  but i got "configure/76yc1d2b-31aa-4b5a-95af-8b0f93b01b00" i would like get just "configure"

Someone can explain me the error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=unit/)(.*)(?=\/)
```

Solves your problem. The trick was to look for the "closing" slash, while in yoursolution you were looking for '?' character

Comment: Thanks man, that was exactly  i need and works perfect

Answer (score 0):

The regex matches everything from the beginning of your url to the end. If you replace .* with [^\/]* (match all but the front slash) then remove your ending group you should get what you want.